# Azure API - get what user logged on workitem

Tags: azure, workitem

I have this application that integrates multiple sources. Currently, I am having troubles with Azure API worklogs. Now, to retrieve a list of worklogs from Azure for the whole team, I use:

`https://extmgmt.dev.TOPSECRET.com/TOPSECRET/_apis/ExtensionManagement/InstalledExtensions/timelog/time-logging-extension/Data/Scopes/Default/Current/Collections/TimeLogData/Documents`

This will return all dozens of thousands of worklogs in format such as this:

```
        {
            "minutes": 480,
            "user": "User",
            "userId": "5e82cb68-1a6b-6811-9278-XXXXXXXXXXX",
            "date": "2023-03-22",
            "dateWeek": "2023-W12",
Currently, t            "workItemId": 28786,
            "type": "Development",
            "comment": "",
            "id": "00002e34-ba94-4036-aaa6-XXXXXXXXXXX",
            "__etag": 1
        },
```

That is great and works for me almost all the time. Unfortunatelly we had an incident with old access key being deprecated and the synchronization was interupted for quite some time.

Now, for the following reports, I need an information in the worklogs about:

- For what date the worklog is logged for
- Date Created
- Date Updated

In the data I receieve there is only "date" information, which is for what date this worklog is logged for. How to retrieve additional information? I assume that the URL I am using is just an extension, and there has to be a native API point where I can get the info I need.

I think there has to be some very simple way how to do that, as for example here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP

I get the workitem and lot of data. I would expect that adding "/worklogs" would be enough to retrieve worklogs for the given workitem, but I assume Azure philosophy is much different to Jira, where I can get this information quite easilly.